# Как написать свою реализацию Exception с определенным message?

Tags: java

Как написать класс MyException таким образом, чтобы в случае ошибки в консоль выводилось сообщение "Wrong number!"?

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            printFilteredNumber(generateNumber());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void printFilteredNumber (Integer number) {
        Integer filtered = Optional.of(number)
                .filter(i -> i > 5)
                .orElseThrow(MyException::new);
        System.out.println(filtered);
    }

    private static Integer generateNumber() {
        return new Random().nextInt(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: отнаследоваться от Exception, в который передается строка

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отнаследуйтесь от базового класса `RuntimeException` или `Exception` и определите конструктор следующим образом:

```java
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    public MyException() {
        super("Wrong number!");
    }
}
```